# Adobe LiveCycle designer - form scripting - changing the field from optional to required

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, adobe, livecycle

I'm trying to make a dynamic PDF form using Adobe LiveCycle designer and have a problem. I have a boolean checkbox field that decides if other text fields are required or optional. I'd like to implement this functionality using form scripting - in the 'changed' event of the checkbox field I'd like to modify other form fields so they become either required or optional. My problem is that I don't know the javascript API and can't find how to modify field 'requiredness'. 
Thanks for help
R

BTW - I'm a beginner ind Adobe's PDF tools but this software is ] a big disappointment for me... And the developer documentation is so weak. Do you know any good online documentation of PDF forms javascript API?

Update: I know how to mark a field required - by setting its mandatory property to mandatory="error". But don't know how to make the field optional.

Comment: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960808/expression-or-reg-ex-for-java-script-or-adobe-livecycle-tools

Please help me here , i am stuck here and its urgent now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make a field be optional you set the mandatory property of the object to "disabled"

Ex: `displayObject.mandatory = "disabled"`

To do so on a condition you do:

```
field.mandatory = (radioGroup.rawValue == 1) ? "error" : "disabled"
```

Where field is the field you are making required/optional and radioGroup is a conditional. In your case it would be `myCheckbox.rawValue == 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
this.getField("Field Name").required = false;
```

or:

```
this.getField("Field Name").required = true;
```