# Expression or reg-ex for java script or adobe livecycle tools

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, expression, sta

What will be the expression for restricting a user to enter either 5 lines or
   375 characters in a scrollable text field?

I tried theese:

`([A-Z])\w+`

`$0</a>`

```js
var re,regs,val;
if(OTHER.rawValue!=null)
{
   val=OTHER.rawValue;
   //re=[a-zA-Z\d\s\-\,\#\.\+]+
   //re=/abc(?!$){5}/ 
   re=/\be(\w*)s\b/m{2,10}$;
   regs=val.match(re);
   if(!regs)
   {
     fieldname.rawValue="";
     xfa.host.messageBox("ANY THING");
     xfa.host.setFocus(fieldname)
   }
}
```

`re=/abc(?!$){5}/`

and many more... but I am not getting exact one to validate either 5
lines or 375 characters

Comment: `^((.*\n){4}.*|.{375})$`

Comment: if you know the pattern or regEx please answer for either 5 line or 375 charactor validation .

Comment: hi Avinash, thanks for your input, but i am trying to use in my code snipet but its not working as per my requirement ..... still its taking more that 5 line or more that 365 character

Comment: form1.page1.OTHER::enter - (JavaScript, client)


function Other_Validation(this)
{
var re,regs,val;
if(OTHER.rawValue!=null)
{
val=OTHER.rawValue;

//re=/^((.*\n){4}.*{375})$/;
re=/^((.+\n){0,4}.+|.{1,375})$/;
regs=val.match(re);
}}                            not woking :(

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**`^((.+\n){0,4}.+|.{1,375})$`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#text_string").focusout(function() {
    var res, text_string = $("#text_string").val();
    if (text_string != null) {

      res = text_string.match(/^((.+\n){0,4}.+|.{1,375})$/);
      console.log(res);
      if (!res) {
        $("#text_string").val("");
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" id="text_string" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: if anybody know any patterns ?? that will be much helpful ,and metion post also not working here .. m not sure may be i am doing some mistake.

Comment: @pushkar kumar    Do you want max (1-5)lines and max length of string 375?

Comment: Yes, max (1-5)lines or max length of string 375 . anyone of them or both

Comment: @pushkar kumar  Then you may wait for this `^((.+\n){0,4}.+|.{1,375})$`.

Comment: form1.page1.OTHER::enter - (JavaScript, client)


function Other_Validation(this)
{
var re,regs,val;
if(OTHER.rawValue!=null)
{
val=OTHER.rawValue;

//re=/^((.*\n){4}.*{375})$/;
re=/^((.+\n){0,4}.+|.{1,375})$/;
regs=val.match(re);
}}                   Its taking any no of line input